# intelligent provisioning in HP DL360 G7

Tags: hp

I am new to the field of servers and I bought a dl360 G7 to start learning about them.
my question is: (asking about HP servers)

do all hp servers have Intelligent provisioning on them or can be installed on them or just for new generation servers like g9 or g10 ??
can my dl360 G7 have intelligent provisioning or does have it and I don't find it ???

Comment: HP ProLiant servers have outstanding provisioning tools. There aren't any available for the G7 due to it is end of life (and off topic for this forum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intelligent Provisioning was introduced in the Gen8 product line.

G7 is too old for production and may not reflect the current technologies you want to learn about.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this document](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docLocale=en_US&docId=a00068072en_us) seems like they support only new generations, mainly G10 (excluding MicroServer Gen10).

Comment: As far as actual deliverables go, the most recent ISO I have for the G7 was from five years ago - April 2017 (5 GB). HP typically stops publishing stuff before that so this hardware is way old and predates. And the EOL stuff is pulled from the web site and are no longer available for download though.  And a couple of the main tools that were in use were discontinued in favor of the newer tools/stuff (that require additional payment?).